# Parse template tags outside of Expression Engine Template

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm running Expression Engine 2.3.0 and using the Channel Images add on.

Part of the site is complex enough that I'm doing it via a plugin rather than using EE's template logic. What I've essentially got is a CodeIgniter controller and views that's called on the site using an EE template tag that I specify.

I'd like to use channel images to make the channel data I'm displaying in my views look a little nicer. Problem is... the Channel Images function doesn't seem to allow me to call it as PHP. Because of the EE template parameters.

So, I decided I'd try to run a template block through the parser. But I'm not getting a result. Any ideas? Or maybe a workaround to call the function directly?

```
<?php $this->EE =& get_instance();

$img_tpl = '{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="'. $item['id'] .'" cover_only="yes"}
            <div style="float:left; display:inline; width:125px;">
                    <a href="{image:url:large}" title="{image:title}"><img src="{image:url:small}" alt="{image:title}" /></a>
                    <p>{image:description}</p>
            </div>
            {/exp:channel_images:images}';

$opts = array('');
$img = $this->EE->output->set_output($this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->parse_globals($img_tpl), array($opts)));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have a hell of a time here. No part of EE's front-end parsing is written thinking that it will be called from outside of EE.

`parse_variables()` and `parse_globals()` don't parse full EE tag pairs (only individual variables), which is why you're getting no results.

I'd really recommend making this work with EE templates.

Answer (score 0):

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1347

I keep revisiting this answer and would like to add how I solved it in ExpressionEngine 3.

```php
// load my own instance of TMPL as myTMPL
ee()->load->library("template", null, "myTMPL");

// get template as a string, and variables as name => value pairs
$template = ee()->myTMPL->fetch_template("mygroup", "mytemplate", false);
$variables = array("name" => "Mr. John Q. Public");

// render the template
$html = ee()->myTMPL->parse_variables($template, array($variables)); // merges variables
ee()->myTMPL->parse($html); // handles conditionals (doesn't seem to run plugins)
$html = ee()->myTMPL->parse_globals(ee()->myTMPL->final_template); // returns output
```